# curl of $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the curl of the vector $(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}$ given that $\vec{\omega} = \nabla\times\vec{u}$ and $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}=\nabla\cdot\vec{\omega}=0$ however I'm not too sure how to go about this.

The curl of a dot product is undefined since the dot product is a scalar and a curl only acts on a vector so how would one take the curl here?

Edit: I have tried another method which leads to another question

Using the identity

$$\vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{v})+\vec{v}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u}) = \nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}) - (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v} - (\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}$$

with $\vec{v}=\vec{u}$. We find that

$$2\vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u}) = \nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}) - 2(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u} \implies (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}=\frac{1}{2}\nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}) - \vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u})$$

So taking the curl of this we find

$$\nabla\times\left[(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\right] = -\nabla\times\vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u})$$

So how do we calculate this final one?

Edit 2: I want the final result to be in the form of a vector calculus identity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $\vec\omega = \nabla\times\vec{u}$ then using the identity

$$\vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{v})+\vec{v}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u}) = \nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}) - (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v} - (\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}$$

with $\vec{v}=\vec{u}$. We find that

$$2\vec{u}\times(\nabla\times\vec{u}) = \nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}) - 2(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u} \implies (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}=\frac{1}{2}\nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}) - \vec{u}\times\vec{\omega}$$

So taking the curl of this we find

$$\nabla\times\left[(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\right] = -\nabla\times\vec{u}\times\vec{\omega}$$

Then recall that

$$\nabla\times(\vec{u}\times\vec{\omega}) = \vec{u}(\nabla\cdot\vec{\omega})-\vec{\omega}(\nabla \cdot\vec{u})+(\vec{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}-(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{\omega} = (\vec{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}-(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{\omega}$$

since $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}=\nabla\cdot\vec{\omega}=0$. Then we are left with

$$\nabla\times\left[(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}\right] = -(\vec{\omega}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u}+(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{\omega}$$

Comment: Why did you accept this answer when it was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec{u}\cdot \nabla = u^i\partial_i$$
$$(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)\vec{u} = (u^i\partial_i)(u^j e_j) = (u^i \partial_i u^j)e_j.$$
$$\nabla \times  [(\vec{u}\cdot \nabla)\vec{u}] = \nabla \times (u^i \partial_i u^j)e_j =$$
$$u^i\partial_i u^j \nabla \times e_j.$$

Just find now $\nabla \times e_j$ andy ou will get the result.

Comment: Hi, I've managed to do it now. See my answer for a simpler form!